# Regex in iOS to limit a text field to only letters and single apostrophies

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

After a text field is returned I want to check if the text provided is valid. Valid means only letters or a single apostrophe, for names.

I'm pretty new to regular expressions. Is there a simple regular expression I can use for this check, or can someone point me towards some reading material where I can learn to compose a regular expression that will fit my needs?

Comment: share some specific example so to have a clear idea...

Comment: Which part needs clarification? A code snippet wouldn't fit in the question as everything other than the bit I'm asking about it's irrelevant. If it's the apostrophe bit then an example of an acceptable entry would be O'Dowed, but an unacceptable entry would be O''Dowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, but you need to show an error in case the input is invalid.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    NSString *const regularExpression = @"^[a-zA-Z']+$";
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regularExpression
                                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                                             error:&error];
    if (error) {
        // Handle error
    }

    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:aString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])];
    return numberOfMatches > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regx should be

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

you can use

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

        if (textField == emailid) {
            NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"] invertedSet];
            NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            ;
            return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same as I commented above, I don't want to check each individual character, I want to check the whole string after it's been completed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function that checks whether the input should be inserted or not and restrict the characters there. Since your restriction is fairly simple there is no need of regular expressions and you can use characters sets.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    [allowedCharacters addCharactersInString:@"'"];

    if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allowedCharacters.invertedSet].location == NSNotFound){
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check each individual character, I want to check the whole string after it's been completed.

Comment: What's the difference? It's safer to check against single characters when inserted, rather then checking when the editing mode finishes, it's usually done that way.

Comment: It changes the flow to check char by char. I agree that would be better, but it's not my call.